# Azure devops group logs with collapsible buttons

Tags: azure-devops

Microsoft documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=powershell#formatting-commands) says we can group logs with collapsible buttons. I tried out the following inline PowerShell script but didn't work. Am I doing anything wrong here?

```
Write-Host "##[group]Beginning of a group"
Write-Host "##[warning]Warning message"
Write-Host "##[error]Error message"
Write-Host "##[debug]Debug text"
Write-Host "##[command]Command-line being run"
Write-Host "##[endgroup]"
```

[image]
[image]

Formatting commands

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update:

These grouping commands are just integrated in pipeline ui (pipelines tab)
Release management uses different logger ui and these are not integrated there.

I tested your sample script , on my side everything work well . What does 'didn't work' specifically refer to? Is there any message in the log?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't see toggle button on group. I have attached the screenshot now.

Comment: I can reproduce your problem in the release pipeline, it seems that Formatting commands work in the build pipeline, but not in the release pipeline. I submitted a [ticket](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1144763/formatting-commands-not-work-in-release-pipleine.html) for you on the Developer Community forum. Our engineers will confirm whether this problem is a bug. If confirmed, they will report this to the product team. The product team would provide the updates if they view it.

Comment: The product group gave a reply:These grouping commands are just integrated in pipeline ui (pipelines tab)
Release management uses different logger ui and these are not integrated there. I update this to the answer. :)